# Java - Trouble with recursion and rectangle placement

Tags: java, android, recursion

I am using Android API's and using the RectF class for rectangles. I have a list of blocks that are on the screen at one time. Each block is given a random position, and then I go through all of the tiles previous, to check if there is an intersection. If there is, it recursively calls the method again to get a new random position and check it against all the other tiles.

I feel like this should work perfectly, except for one thing that may be affecting it. Since recursion opens up so many instances of a method, it needs to finish them off, so I don't know if the rectangle is just being drawn at the initial position, and the rest of the calls are doing nothing?

I have tried quite a few different methods and this seems to be the closest, but something weird is happening and I cant figure it out.

Start method:

```
    private void start() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(Game.STATE == Game.State.Playing) {                  
                removeFailedTiles();

                Random deathRate = new Random();
                int i = deathRate.nextInt(100);
                if(i % 10 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Death tile");
                    activeDeathTiles.add(new DeathTile(getRandomPosition()));
                    //System.out.println(activeDeathTiles.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Normal Tile");
                    activeTiles.add(new Tile(tileLifetime, getRandomPosition()));
                }

            }

            if(Game.STATE == Game.State.Lost) {
                timerTask.cancel();
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, tileDelay);

}
```

Get Random Position method:

```
private RectF getRandomPosition() {
    int screenWidth = (int) Game.SCREEN_WIDTH;
    int screenHeight = (int) Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    RectF pos = new RectF();

    Random random = new Random();
    int maxX = (int) (screenWidth - (Tile.TILE_WIDTH * 1.5f)), minX = (int) (Tile.TILE_WIDTH / 1.5f);
    int maxY = (int) (screenHeight - (Tile.TILE_HEIGHT * 1.5f)), minY = (int) (Tile.TILE_HEIGHT / 1.5f);

    pos.top = random.nextInt(maxY - minY) + minY;
    pos.left = random.nextInt(maxX - minX) + minX;
    pos.bottom = pos.top + Tile.TILE_HEIGHT;
    pos.right = pos.left + Tile.TILE_HEIGHT;

    if(isOverlap(pos)) {
        return getRandomPosition();
    } else {
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Helper methods:

```
private List<RectF> getAllTiles() {
    List<RectF> allTiles = new ArrayList<RectF>();

    for(RectF t : activeDeathTiles) 
        allTiles.add(t);
    for(RectF t : activeTiles) 
        allTiles.add(t);

    return allTiles;
}

private boolean isOverlap(RectF position) {

    for(RectF r : getAllTiles()) {
        if(RectF.intersects(position, r)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If someone could please help me figure out what is going wrong here that would be stellar!

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with this code?

Comment: The blocks are still placed on top of each other, although im saying if there is a collision to get a new position

Comment: Please accept the answer given by MadEqua if this has solved your problem, by hitting the checkmark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your code seems fine exept for this typo on `getRandomPosition()`:

```
pos.right = pos.left + Tile.TILE_HEIGHT;
```

which should be

```
pos.right = pos.left + Tile.TILE_WIDTH;
```

I'm not sure if that can be the root cause of the problem, but there's always the option of not using recursion and use a loop, should be easier to debug:

```
private RectF getRandomPosition() {
    RectF pos = new RectF();

    int screenWidth = (int) Game.SCREEN_WIDTH;
    int screenHeight = (int) Game.SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    Random random = new Random();
    int maxX = (int) (screenWidth - (Tile.TILE_WIDTH * 1.5f)), minX = (int) (Tile.TILE_WIDTH / 1.5f);
    int maxY = (int) (screenHeight - (Tile.TILE_HEIGHT * 1.5f)), minY = (int) (Tile.TILE_HEIGHT / 1.5f);

    do {
        pos.top = random.nextInt(maxY - minY) + minY;
        pos.left = random.nextInt(maxX - minX) + minX;
        pos.bottom = pos.top + Tile.TILE_HEIGHT;
        pos.right = pos.left + Tile.TILE_WIDTH;
    }
    while(isOverlap(pos));

    return pos;
}
```

Bear in mind that if the screen gets too full the loop may not be able to finish. To fix it, something like a maximum number of loops before giving up can be added.

Comment: The tiles are squares so width height is the same but technically yes thats right but wouldnt do it. The way this works the screen will never be that full so it should be okay on that end. Il try the loop

Comment: The loop you have there doesnt do anything? Shouldnt i be resetting the position in there?

Comment: Writing on `pos.top`, `pos.left`, etc is effectively resetting the position.

Comment: Ohh i didnt see the do { thats why i was confused

Comment: +1 Yep - avoid recursion wherever possible - although elegant, it's more difficult to reason about and can hurt performance by the way it abuses the stack.